# How to customise color in Switches on Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

[image]

i have retrieved the code from get bootstrap

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

how to customize the css?
to make it exactly like this

Comment: You can't do that with this code because the toggle button's are controlled by svg images which we can't color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add these CSS rules as a stating point :

```css
.form-switch .form-check-input {
        width: 3em !important;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='4' fill='red'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}

.form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='4' fill='green'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}

.form-check-input, .form-check-input:checked {
    background-color: grey !important;
    border-color: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked great thanks alot!